# How do I add the YouTube notifications to my server and iOS application?

Tags: ios, youtube, push-notification, websub

It's been 3 days that I'm stuck on this problem.
I am developing an iOS application that will show a YouTube channel with its video. I would like the application to send push notifications to the user whenever there is a new video uploaded on YouTube.

I looked at https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/push_notifications and https://github.com/pubsubhubbub/ but I don't understand what is the endpoint they are waiting for.

What is the code I have to write to be able to push notifications on iOS? Where should it be stored?